# Blank response with django + unicodecsv

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm simply trying to have Django export a csv of a Model object. I've tried a lot of different things and reduced my code to the following example which still does not work.

I've eliminated all logic for building the file, turned off all context processors (thinking they might interfere somehow), and adjusted my model to ensure that all fields are unicode (this one doesn't even matter in the code example).

I changed out unicodecsv for regular csv and still have the same issue so I'm assuming the issue is somewhere within Django and not the view.

Expected output is a csv file with the header row. Actual output is a completely empty file.

views.py:

```
def export_list_to_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv',)
    response['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-download';
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="my_product_list.csv"'

    writer = unicodecsv.writer(response)

    headers = ["name", "description", "website", "price", "creation_date"]

    writer.writerow(headers)

    return response
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is that "runserver_plus" which Werkzeug uses, for whatever reason, does not support building responses like this. This function works fine with the regular "runserver", or gunicorn.